# Rails app wont set database.yml

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a new rails application that i try to deploy to Heroku. However the database.yml build step is skipped.

When i do `heroku run bash` and `cat config/database.yml` I don't see any changed made by Heroku.

I already tried recreating the Heroku app, but that didn't solve the problem

Is there anything i'm missing at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Heroku has stopped writing the database.yml in the buildpack for rails 4.1  (https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/426)

Comment: Good to know that. But in the best practice, you shouldn't check in `database.yml` file in the source control, that file should be added to git ignore. It's because the file `database.yml` will be changed based on the development and deployment environments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do not agree with you, you can set the database.yml information with ENV keys, and you can set different information based on environment. I believe that it should be checked in git.

Comment: I just said "in best practice". It depends on your deployment strategy ;)